# Why in my ngrx effect a condition inside Array.map function is neccessary?

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have a problem with understanding certain thing in ngrx create effect() function.

In following code why I need to have `tag.Id != 0 &&` condition in tags.map(...) in order for this effect to work ? As far as I know the Array.map method doest not require any condition and just excecutes the code for every single array item....

```
public removeCurrentTagGroup$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(TagGroupsActions.RemoveCurrentTagGroup),
      withLatestFrom(this.store$.select(SelectChoosenIds)),
      withLatestFrom(this.store$.select(SelectTagsToDelete)),

      mergeMap(([[action, tagIds], tags]) => {
        return forkJoin(
          tags.map(
            (tag) => tag.Id != 0 && this.phobossService.deleteTagGroup(tag.Id.toString()).pipe(map(() => ({ syncId: tag.Id.toString() })))
          )
        );
      }),
      map((tagIds: OperationSave[]) => {
        return TagGroupsActions.RemoveCurrentTagGroupSuccess({ tagGroupIds: tagIds });
      })
    )
  );
```

If only I remove this condition ane leave only the bare request my code turn red and I got following error statement :

```
Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<[[TypedAction<"[TagGroups] REMOVE_CURRENT_TAG_GROUP">, string[]], TagGroup[]], { syncId: string; }[]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<[[TypedAction<"[TagGroups] REMOVE_CURRENT_TAG_GROUP">, string[]], TagGroup[]], OperationSave[]>'.
  Type '{ syncId: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'OperationSave[]'.
    Type '{ syncId: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'OperationSave': success, namets(2345)
```

Edit:

This also works, but wont work without checking for length in forkJoin()

```
public removeCurrentTagGroup$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(TagGroupsActions.RemoveCurrentTagGroup),
      withLatestFrom(this.store$.select(SelectChoosenIds)),

      mergeMap(([action, tagIds]) => {
        return forkJoin(
          tagIds.length > 0 && tagIds.map((tag) => this.phobossService.deleteTagGroup(tag).pipe(map(() => ({ syncId: tag }))))
        );
      }),
      map((tagIds: OperationSave[]) => {
        return TagGroupsActions.RemoveCurrentTagGroupSuccess({ tagGroupIds: tagIds });
      })
    )
  );
```

Comment: Can you post tags class? I think you have problem with the BE of deleteTagGroup

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean :) this method is part of external library that I cant change and it works well. Im able to delete items on list, single or multiple(that the reason why there is an array) but what is the point of having obligatory condition before using array.map ?

Comment: for my opinion... but without code is difficult.. you call deleteTagGroup with an id set to 0 and the BE try to delete element in the database... but Id 0 not exist...